# Can the public WiFi provider see information I transfer when I use HTTPS

Tags: security, https, wifi

I'm using a public WiFi hotspot and I am wondering if I browse websites that use HTTPS protocol, is the WiFi provider (if he logs the data transfer on his router) able to see what information I exchange with the Web server?

Sorry, I'm a noob in this stuff. I'm just wondering if I can log into private stuff like Bank account if their website uses HTTPS or if it is still not secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WiFi provider essentially has access to all the same information that a traditional ISP would.  They can see who you are communicating with, but they cannot see the contents of your encrypted traffic.

That being said, a malicious WiFi provider could still hit you with attacks like poisoned DNS. Also, if you visit plain HTTP sites, that traffic is visible and also a good point for initiating a MitM attack.  To make a long story short, I, personally, would never do banking or any other kind of sensitive activity on a public network.

Answer (score 0):

Just assume that any Wi-Fi is not secure. Some are more secure than others but public Wi-Fi is mostly unsecured and that leaves you open to hacking... that is if the Wi-Fi you think you are on isn't a fake anyway. It takes minutes for a hacker to set up a false Wi-Fi hotspot and start gathering all your transmissions (using free software). The only safe way to go on line is with a VPN 
regards
Bryan from Venom UK